# Does the sparse model influence inference time?

Tags: macos, pytorch, inference

I used the same model structure and the same dataset to train the CNN model several times, however, I got different inference time. I only changed the learning rate or repeated the training process with all same parameters, and those models show different inference times when all the settings were the same.

So, I propose the above question.

MacBook Pro 16', PyTorch=1.12.0, CPU is only used.

Thanks!